# Copiar Macro entre arquivos no VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba, macro

Olá, tenho um arquivo (chamarei de WB1) em Excel, com duas macros. Uma delas (macroA) faz um tratamento de dados e formatação. A outra (macroB) cria um novo arquivo .xlsm (WB2) e copia alguns dados do WB1.

Porém, WB2 precisa ter também a macroA.

Como posso fazer essa "importação" de uma macro entre os arquivos no VBA? O código de importação ficaria dentro da macroB.

Comment: Veja como programar no [VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) ou a seguinte resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956837/7690982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, tem um jeito mais simples. É só criar um arquivo novo baseado no seu atual. Segue o código ilustrando isso:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MacroA()
    Debug.Print "MacroA"
End Sub

Sub MacroB()
    Dim ArquivoNovo As String
    ArquivoNovo = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ArquivoNovo
    
    Dim wbNovo As Workbook
    Set wbNovo = Workbooks.Open(ArquivoNovo)
    
    'Para usar comandos no arquivo original: ThisWorkbook
    MsgBox "Arquivo original= " & ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    'Para usar comandos no arquivo novo (copiado): wbNovo
    MsgBox "Arquivo original= " & wbNovo.Name
End Sub
```